# Escaping special character bash

Tags: javascript, bash, escaping, echo

Im writing a bash file to automate some of the setup for creating a webpage. The following piece of code is used as part of creating a node server.

```
echo const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { >> index.js
```

The arrow part of the code messes up the output since the > character is used for redirection. My index.js file ends up looking like this:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) =
```

I have tried to escape the special character using a backslash and i've tried using single quotes to turn it into a string. Like this:

```
echo const server = http.createServer((req, res) =\> { >> index.js
```

```
'echo const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { >> index.js'
```

However this simply produces the following in my index.js:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) =\
```

```
'const server = http.createServer((req, res) =
```

Comment: Tried `echo "..."` yet?

Comment: `echo "const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {" >> index.js`

Comment: echo "..." works but maybe outputting it as a string is wrong to begin with. As i now have my js code as a string in my code which isn't ideal.

Comment: There isn't anything inherently wrong with it but if you want to take a different approach (e.g. editing a template file and installing it) and get stuck on that then feel free to open a new question for it.

Comment: @tjm3772 check my comments to the answer below where im a little bit more specific. But yeah i think ill look into it some more and try something else. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "..." for strings.

```bash
echo "const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {" >> index.js
```

does the job.

Comment: This works but maybe outputting it as a string is wrong to begin with. As i now have my js code as a string in my code which isn't ideal.

Comment: @pumpchief A JS file is text. What do you expect text to be, other than just a string?

Comment: @SebastianSimon My bad should have been more specific ment that the text is being treated as a string in JS. ```echo "const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {"``` Outputs ```"const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {"``` when i wan't it to be outputting ```const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {```

Comment: `echo "const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {"` does not output `"const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {"` in bash in a standard environment. If that's the output you're getting then you should edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating that behavior.

Comment: I strongly believe echoing code using bash it's not the best way to automate a web page generation. So, I would suggest using different means (i.e. Jinja templating using Python). My answer was meant to reply to your question.
As @tjm3772 was indicating, in a standard bash (sh, zsh) env. double quotes are not present in the output

Comment: Yeah turns out i was just being dumb. I had a batch file not a bash file and my sleepless self couldn't tell the difference. "..." Is correct for bash, thanks for the help all